# html5 - Canvas - Createjs - negative space in graphics drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs

I have a complex situation where i need to draw a shape with the lineTo() and drawCircle() methods, but there is a negative space behavior depending on which direction i draw the lines.

```
//draw from right to left   
var shape2 = new createjs.Shape();
    shape2.graphics.beginFill('blue').moveTo(300,200).lineTo(0,200).lineTo(0,300).lineTo(300,300).closePath();
    shape2.graphics.drawCircle(280,250,100)
```

Look at this JsFiddle :)
https://jsfiddle.net/zOgs/3epv7o54/

Can someone explain to me why the blue circle make a negative space ..? And how to avoid that behavior...

(I have tried to change the compositeOperation param of the shape instance, but it's seems to have no effect...)

Thx !

**EDIT 1:**

I have made a more accurate example of my working case. Please look at this JsFiddle and move your mouse on the canvas. You'll see there isn't any probleme from RIGHT TO LEFT... but negatives spaces appears from LEFT TO RIGHT !!
(move quickly for better view)

https://jsfiddle.net/zOgs/psa3x9y2/

I don't understand exactly why, and i can't find any valid workaround...
(no caching possible because of performance reasons, no composeOperation because of background troubles)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1** (removing two previously proposed workarounds)

I think I've found a solution: Setting the fill again before the circle is drawn seems to address it.

In terms of your example, that would mean modifying the last line of the excerpt above to read `shape2.graphics.beginFill('blue').drawCircle(280,250,100);`.

**EDIT 2**

In response to your remarks and updated jsfiddle, you could also try setting `shape3.compositeOperation = "xor";` right after your `Shape()` instantiation.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/93gv1e06/

Comment: Thx, but my work case i much more complex. I need to use lineTo() and i don't know which side i will be drawing, so i need a solution that works with both side !

Comment: Yes you're right, i have test this solution before :) But i have another constraint !! i must set an alpha to the shape... With that solution, rect and circle will not have anymore the same alpha value... Pretty complex situation huh ;)

Comment: Ah yes, I see your problem, that is quite a complex situation indeed :)

Comment: Have you tried `shape3.compositeOperation = "xor";` before drawing the shape? Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/93gv1e06/

Comment: Hum... i can not make it working with my working example....... let me come back later. Thx

Comment: Can't use compositeOperation because it's mess with the background... Example:  [https://jsfiddle.net/zOgs/93gv1e06/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/zOgs/93gv1e06/7/)

Comment: That's unfortunate :/ At the moment, I don't have any idea how to address those artifacts